# Divide a number by a Vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

Is it possible to divide a number by a `Vector3`? For example, how can I divide 1 by the scale vector of an object to resize it's child according to it's parent scale without making a new `Vector3` applying values of each axis respectivly?

Comment: No, afaik there is no such thing like `1 / Vector3`

Comment: I would recommend you to write extension method for Vector3 if you need to do it many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method build-in

but you can simply add an [extension method](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) once like

```c#
public static class Vector3Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inverts a scale vector by dividing 1 by each component
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector3 Invert(this Vector3 vec)
    {
        return new Vector3(1 / vec.x, 1 / vec.y, 1 / vec.z);
    }
}
```

than later in all your scripts you just have to do e.g.

```c#
var parentSize = transform.parent.lossyScale; // e.g. 1, 2, 3

var invertedParentSize = parentSize.Invert();

// -> 1.0, 0.5, 0.333..
```

Comment: I think 'invert' word means vector with opposite direction, its more looks like the vector^(-1)

Comment: @caxapexac so how would you call it? what you mean is already simply covered by `- Vector3` or [Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html). Since it is supposed to be used for "inverting" a scale vector I "came up" with that name for it ;)

Comment: @derHuro, I don't know exactly right word for this behaviour but I assume it's something like PowMinusOne()

Comment: @derHugo I would call it `Reciprocal()`. That is ultimately what you do. `Invert()` is really a misleading term and imho bad naming

Comment: @Neuron well as already said you can call it whatever you wish to call it ... I used Invert because as you see it basically does exactly that, invert the scaling of the parent object. I'm aware it is probably not the correct mathematical term but for me rather a description what it is used for. For me in my projects that name made sense .. but sure feel free to call it whatever you want ;) You in you can call it `Reciprocal` but I can tell you that I would every time have to look it up in order to understand what it does ;) (I'm not native English)

Comment: @derHugo yea, I am not native English either. I assume you speak native German (which I do too), in which case it is also called "reziproke Wert", so language is not really an excuse ;) and words in programming are important. in any project, when you work with others, words must have an elegance, simplicity and truth to them. If the word is new to you, great. a new word you can learn and get used to. i would accept your excuse if you only ever used that word in your own project and never shared it with anyone, but you are using that word on SO. Don't underestimate how many people just copy...

Comment: code into their projects which many people are working on. I think if you want your answer to be good, you should not use `Invert` because to anyone somewhat custom with mathematical notation this is really misleading. It may actually cause some developer on some project to use this method. it then goes by untested and lands in production code. So I am not trying to have a philosophical discussion here, but I think it really matters and you could improve your answer by changing the name of that function ;) cheers

Comment: concluding.. "you can call it whatever you wish to call it ..." -> in your own project, not on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as a `Vector3` is not a Scalar value.

You can however to mathematical functions using the individual parts of a `Vector3(x,y,z)`.

EX:

```
var number = 5 * someVector.x;
```

Comment: and that's exactly what OP didn't want to do ;) `witout making a new Vector3 applying values of each axis`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, but if you guarantee all three axis will change scale to the same value like (1, 1, 1) to (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) or at least at the same proportion (100% to 70% in all axis), then you can save into an int the value os one of those axis.

```
int number = gameObject.transform.localScale.x;
```

Then, on the child objects you just use the number:

```
gameObject.transform.localScale *= gameObject.transform.parent.getComponent<someClass>().number;
```

int variables can only store one value, so you can't use the same variable to allocate data of three axis simultaneously.

the method I gave you is to copy the scale, if you want to keep the size of the childs even if the parent changes it scale then you divide 1/parent scale

```
int number = 1/gameObject.transform.localScale.x;

gameObject.transform.localScale *= gameObject.transform.parent.getComponent<someClass>().number;
```