# Unity - No Found Solution to Child Scale Inheritance

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent, scaling

Fairly new to Unity and have tried several solutions without success.  I have read so many forum posts but none are working for me.

I have been attempting to snap game objects to other game objects at runtime (such as to equip ship parts to a ship).  The script works as intended but the child objects continue to be scaled with the parent object.

I have tried attaching scaling scripts that dynamically scale the child object based on the parent object scale.  I've tried stepping through the logical way one would go about doing this. I have tried hierarchal fixes using empty game objects and nothing seems to be maintaining a constant global scale for my child objects.  Maybe someone can see something I am missing.

Please ignore other issues that may be in the code at this point unless they directly are affecting the scaling issue.  But suggestions are welcome.  Interested in learning all I can.

**-Hierarchy-** 
Ship   (scale (2,2,2))  parent of the parent 
-Empty Object  (scale (0.5,0.5,0.5)) this is the parent set to the same         scale as the snappable object

```cs
public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pickUpDestination;
    public Transform snapDestination;
    public Vector3 snapPointPos;
    private bool isSnapped;
    public bool isClicked;
    public float unsnapMouseDist = 0.5f;
    public float distCheck;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        distCheck = Vector3.Distance(pickUpDestination.position, snapPointPos);
        if (distCheck >= unsnapMouseDist && isClicked)
        {
            isSnapped = false;
            transform.SetParent(pickUpDestination);
            transform.position = transform.parent.position;
            Debug.Log("UNSNAPPED");
        }
        else if (distCheck <= unsnapMouseDist && isClicked)
        {
            isSnapped = true;
            transform.SetParent(snapDestination, true);
            transform.position = transform.parent.position;
            Debug.Log("SNAPPED!");
        }
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Parent =" + transform.parent.name);
        }
        Debug.Log("Global Scale = " + transform.lossyScale);
        Debug.Log("Local Scale = " + transform.localScale);
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isClicked = true;
        Debug.Log("Clicked = " + isClicked);
        if (isSnapped == false)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            transform.SetParent(pickUpDestination);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider snap)
    {
        if (snap.gameObject.CompareTag("Snap Point"))
        {
            snapPointPos = snap.transform.position;
            snapDestination = snap.transform;
            transform.rotation = snap.transform.rotation;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isClicked = false;
        Debug.Log("Clicked = " + isClicked);
        if (isSnapped == false)
        {
            this.transform.parent = null;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Scaling Script:

```cs
public class Scaler : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform parent;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
            parent = transform.parent;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x / parent.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y / parent.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z / parent.localScale.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809777/divide-a-number-by-a-vector3 ?

Comment: I have tried to do something similar using each axis of the parent and child for the math but not quite in this manner.  I will give it a try thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html) is the combined effects of all parent scales on that object (some caveats but not likely to apply here).
[`localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) is the scale effect of only that object (the numbers you see in the transform inspector)

```
var trueScale == new Vector3( 
                     desiredScale.x / parentTransform.lossyScale.x, 
                     desiredScale.y / parentTransform.lossyScale.y, 
                     desiredScale.z / parentTransform.lossyScale.z);

transform.localScale = trueScale;
```

Comment: I have been trying to use lossyScale of the child but I don't know if I have tried to use the parent's lossyScale in my math yet.  I seem to have been misunderstanding what lossyScale was.  I will try it out and mark as answered once I do.  Appreciate the assistance.